# Error con funcion de saludo

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo una funcion en la cual dependiendo el horario, el usuario recibe un saludo.

```
<?php
//hora Argentina
//agregar hora europea date_default_timezone_set('');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');

function saludo($forma) {
    $hora = date("H");
    foreach($forma as $formas) {
        if($hora > $formas[0] && $hora < $formas[1]) return $formas[2];
    }
}

$forma = array(
    array(0, 7, "Good night"),
    array(6, 12, "Good morning"),
    array(13, 20, "Good afternoon"),
    array(21, 24, "Good night")
);

echo saludo($forma);
?>
```

Como resultado tendria que decir `"Good night"`, pero esta en blanco. No se que estoy haciendo mal ya que en un momento el saludo esta bien.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te falta poner el signo de `=` en las comparaciones de ambos extremos, de lo contrario la condición no se cumplirá cuando la hora sea: `0,6,13,21` ni cuando sea `7,12,20,24`, porque no preguntas si es *mayor **o igual*** a... y *menor **o igual** a*. Por eso, si la hora es `21` por ejemplo, nunca se cumplirá la condición, por eso devuelve `NULL`.

Si pones la comparación así debería funcionar:

```
if($hora >= $formas[0] && $hora <= $formas[1]) return $formas[2];
```

Comment: Gracias Cedano, ahora en Argentina son las 10pm, voy a ver que pasa cuando llegue a las 12. Ahora esta funcionando.